# jquery - "click" on keypress?

Tags: jquery, click, keypress, enter

I have an ajax search form that works fine if you click "submit" in that you enter a zipcode, click the "Enter" button and up pops results instantly.  I'm trying to make it so that if the user presses "enter" on the keyboard, it has the same effect.  It looks like it's submitting, but no results come up...

I tried:

```
  if($('#search').length) {
        $('#zipcode').keyup(function(e) {
          if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
            $('#search').submit();
          }
        });
  }
```

Comment: you shouldn't need javascript for this. Browsers generally do this automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldnt have to "fake" a click. Make sure your "enter" button is either:

```
<input type="submit">
```

Or

```
<button type="submit">
```

And it should submit the form on pressing enter.

The other potential problem is that the Ajax code is bound to the button's click event, rather than the form's submit event.

```
$('button').click(...); // is wrong
$('form').submit(...); // is right
```

Answer (score 1):

Use .click() with no parameters

Comment: How does that help?  It already works if you click the button.  I want it to work if a user hits enter on the keyboard... How does using click make that happen?

Comment: Right... You want to simulate a click... So, just like you have your listener setup with if (event.keycode == 13) $('#submit').click(); clicks on the submit button. Isnt that what you're asking?

Comment: He's suggesting you invoke a click event yourself by doing something like `$('#submitButton').click();`.

Comment: You should also look into jquery ui's autocomplete. It does what (I think) you're trying to accomplish with this